# Debugging interactive matplotlib figures in Jupyter notebooks

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, interactive

The example below should highlight the point that you click on, and change the title of the graph to show the label associated with that point.

If I run this Python script as a script, when I click on a point I will get an error " line 15, in onpick
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index", which is expected. `event.ind` is a list, and I need to change that to `ind = event.ind[0]` to be correct here.

However, when I run this in a Jupyter notebook, the figure appears, but the error is silently ignored, so it just appears that the code does not work. Is there a way to get Jupyter to show me that an error has occurred?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
ax.plot(x, 'bo', picker=5)

# this is the transparent marker for the selected data point
marker, = ax.plot([0], [0], 'yo', visible=False, alpha=0.8, ms=15)

def onpick(event):
    ind = event.ind
    ax.set_title('Data point {0} is labeled "{1}"'.format(ind, labels[ind]))
    marker.set_visible(True)
    marker.set_xdata(x[ind])
    marker.set_ydata(x[ind])

    ax.figure.canvas.draw()  # this line is critical to change the linewidth

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

plt.show()
```

Comment: If you leave out matplotlib (and maybe find an example where an error occurs with only inbuild modules, e.g. creating an error while running a tkinter app), and tagging this with the `python` tag, it might get more attention.